# How do I convert a Groovy class constructor into a Closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

So Groovy has this relatively handy syntax to convert methods into closures, e.g.

```
[1,2,3].each { println it }

// is equivalent to

[1,2,3].each this.&println
```

But how do I convert a class Constructor, e.g

```
[1,2,3].collect { new Thing( it ) }

// is equivalent to

[1,2,3].collect ????
```

Groovy's reflection has `Thing.constructors` List to inspect, but I can't figure out where to put the ampersand in `Thing.constructors[0]`.

Comment: This is a good question. I would imagine that it's not possible, as Groovy inherits Java's distinction between methods and constructors (i.e. constructors are not just class methods); but, who knows? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`invokeConstructor` metaClass method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaObjectProtocol.html#invokeConstructor%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) that invokes a constructor for the given arguments.

```
class Thing {
    Thing(Integer num) { this.num = num }
    Integer num
}

[1,2,3].collect Thing.metaClass.&invokeConstructor
```

Comment: Awesome, it works. I would have preferred something more concise like `Thing.&new` but that's Java for you. Do you know if there are performance benefits or drawbacks of this over `{ new Thing( it ) }`?